# convert to string with and without reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been looking for code to get CPUID in Linux and came across several good examples. These are specific questions between difference in implementation. Below are unsigned integers and it uses reinterpret_cast with size_t as 12

```
struct CPUVendorID{
unsigned int ebx;
unsigned int edx;
unsigned int ecx;

string toString() const {
    return string(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(this), 12);
}
};
...
CPUVendorID vendorID { .ebx = ebx, .edx = edx, .ecx = ecx };
string vendor = vendorID.toString();
```

another form of to get the same output with size_t as 4 is given below:

```
string vendor;
vendor += string((const char *)&cpuID.EBX(), 4);
vendor += string((const char *)&cpuID.EDX(), 4);
vendor += string((const char *)&cpuID.ECX(), 4);
cout << "CPU vendor = " << vendor << endl;
```

Both output 12 character string. Can someone explain me what is happening in the reinterpret_cast statement above ? I find this way of implementation very elegant, but I don't know why its working obviously 4*3=12. But, how does it manage to concatenate data from the 3 ebx, edx and ecx?

CPU's manufacturer ID string – a twelve-character ASCII string stored in EBX, EDX, ECX (in that order) [CPUID wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID)

Comment: C and C++ are different languages! Don't spam tags

Comment: You could simply say: `unsigned int result[3];` and then `std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(result), sizeof result)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB your suggestions do work also. Thank you. I will probably go with your suggestion since its not user dependent. But do you know why the string concatenates when the 1st example uses (this) pointer ?

Comment: @itsnevertoobadtoaskforhelp: Your code is making assumptions on implementation details, namely on the layout of the class. Such assumptions are not portable.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Is your solution portable ? Sorry for the silly question. But this is a bit advanced for me.

Comment: @itsnevertoobadtoaskforhelp: Yes, the layout of arrays is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain me what is happening in the reinterpret_cast statement above?

The structure address `this` coincides with the address of its first member, which is `int ebx`. Since the following members are of the same type, there is no padding between them, so that this code treats the three `int` members as an `int[3]` array.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Concise and explains everything. Thank you. It also explains @Kerrek SB suggestion

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that there will be no padding, it just happens to be the case.

Comment: @KerrekSB There are requirements with regards to structure layout and member alignment and there is a requirement that there is no padding between members of an array. If you are going to code up a compiler that inserts unnecessary padding between members I would not use it and actively recommend my friends to avoid your compiler. In other words, your comment may be pedantically correct but is useless in practice.